# Control key acts as it is stuck while typing

Tags: chromebook

I'm on Chromebook and it has just started doing this again.

The last time the control key acted as it was stuck it fixed after about a month but I don't how it got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are describing is [sticky keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_keys#:%7E:text=Sticky%20Keys%20is%20an%20accessibility,syndrome%20called%20the%20Emacs%20Pinky). Sticky keys allow users to press and release modifier keys (like control) while having the key remain "active" in the OS. For example, to press 'control-alt-delete' using sticky keys, one would only need to press and release control, then alt, then delete. Control and alt wouldn't need be continuously held before hitting delete.

You can find how to disable sticky keys on ChromeOS through [here](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/177893#onehandshortcut):

From "Use keyboard shortcuts one key at a time":

> 1. At the bottom right, select the time. Or press Alt + Shift + s.
> 2. Select Settings.
> 3. At the bottom, select Advanced.
> 4. In the "Accessibility" section, select Manage accessibility features.
> 5. To perform keyboard shortcuts by entering them sequentially, under "Keyboard," turn on Enable sticky keys.

In your case, you should expect 'Enable sticky keys' to already be enabled. Instead, try disabling it.

Comment: It didn't work the type of Chromebook I have doesn't have sticky keys. I have an Asus Chromebook.

Comment: Darn. Sorry about that. Hope you're able to solve your issue!

Comment: Yeah, I hope so too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to you could just disable ctrl in the chromebook settings
under keyboard

Comment: Maybe you could clarify this a little. "Settings" usually refers to software, and aren't usually accessible under keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Sticky keys was not on. rodreguiez is right. The ctrl key can be remapped or disabled in Settings > Device > Keyboard. For me this solved the problem instantly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1146658)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1146658)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.

I went to settings, turned on the on screen keyboard and clicked on the control key on that. It then worked normally.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).